# CPU Usage (%) MBean on Sun JVM

Tags: jvm, cpu-usage

The overview tab of a process on jconsole shows me the CPU Usage percentage. Is there a MBean that gives me this value? What is its ObjectName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a direct MBean within ManagementFactory. The closest is http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemLoadAverage() which can be used to calculate the CPU used by the whole system.

However [this URL has suggested a method](http://knight76.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-get-java-cpu-usage-jvm-instance.html) based on the source code of jconsole

Comment: Not the (simple) solution I wanted, but seems to be the only way.

Comment: Mind that the cast is to com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean!

Comment: The URL you gave works for Java 7. `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` is not accessible with Java 6...

Answer (score 22):

Update:  In Java 7 you can do it like so:

```
public static double getProcessCpuLoad() throws MalformedObjectNameException, ReflectionException, InstanceNotFoundException {

    MBeanServer mbs    = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName name    = ObjectName.getInstance("java.lang:type=OperatingSystem");
    AttributeList list = mbs.getAttributes(name, new String[]{ "ProcessCpuLoad" });

    if (list.isEmpty())     return Double.NaN;

    Attribute att = (Attribute)list.get(0);
    Double value  = (Double)att.getValue();

    if (value == -1.0)      return Double.NaN;

    return ((int)(value * 1000) / 10.0);        // returns a percentage value with 1 decimal point precision
}
```

----- original answer below -----

In Java 7 you can use the hidden methods of `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`:

```
getProcessCpuLoad()    // returns the CPU usage of the JVM

getSystemCpuLoad()     // returns the CPU usage of the whole system
```

Both values are returned as a double between 0.0 and 1.0 so simply multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
System.out.println(osBean.getProcessCpuLoad() * 100);
System.out.println(osBean.getSystemCpuLoad()  * 100);
```

Since these are hidden, undocumented, methods that exist in `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` package and not in the `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` there is a risk that they will not be available in some JVMs or in future updates, so you should decide if you're willing to take that risk or not.

see https://www.java.net/community-item/hidden-java-7-features-%E2%80%93-system-and-process-cpu-load-monitoring for more.

Comment: Note: These methods are *not* available in Java 6.

Comment: For some reason your first example gives a different value than com.sun.management.`OperatingSystemMXBean::getProcessCpuLoad`. Value from example is ~ 100 times bigger. Any insights on why is it different?

Answer (score 1):

I modified a code from internet, like this, then I tested that and the result almost match the linux ps command's result.

/** below is the code */

```
public float getCpuUsed() {

    /** get a MXBean  */
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean osMXBean =
    (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) 
    ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();


    /** set old timestamp values */
    long previousJvmProcessCpuTime = osMXBean.getProcessCpuTime();


    int sleepTime = 350;
    /** sleep for a while to use to calculate */
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException occurred while MemoryCollector sleeping...");
    }

    /** elapsed process time is in nanoseconds */
    long elapsedProcessCpuTime = osMXBean.getProcessCpuTime() - previousJvmProcessCpuTime;

    /** elapsed uptime is in milliseconds */

    long elapsedJvmUptime = sleepTime ;

    /** total jvm uptime on all the available processors */
    //long totalElapsedJvmUptime = elapsedJvmUptime * osMXBean.getAvailableProcessors() ;
    long totalElapsedJvmUptime = elapsedJvmUptime;
    //System.out.println("echo cpu processors num " + osMXBean.getAvailableProcessors());

    /** calculate cpu usage as a percentage value
       to convert nanoseconds to milliseconds divide it by 1000000 and to get a percentage multiply it by 100 */
    float cpuUsage = elapsedProcessCpuTime / (totalElapsedJvmUptime * 10000F);



    return (float)(Math.round(cpuUsage*10)/10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iff you are using UNIX based OS then it's way much easier

```
final OperatingSystemMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
if (mxBean instanceof UnixOperatingSystemMXBean) {
  return ((UnixOperatingSystemMXBean) mxBean).getSystemCpuLoad() * 100.0;
}
```