# Can java get the processor current information?

Tags: java, command, distributed-computing, distributed-system, processor

Is there any way in java to get information about how much work is doing the processor? I'm building a system where a proxy redirects a petition to one of three servers (each of those in a diferent computer) I want the proxy to send that petition to the server that has the processor with fewer load. Is there anything in java that can do that task? Any command in win10 / linux that I can call from my java program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CPU Usage (%) MBean on Sun JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044841/cpu-usage-mbean-on-sun-jvm)